# How to return the oauth token in url for mobile clients

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

**Description**

In the default ASP.NET Web API 2 template, when requesting a token by sending a `POST` request to the Token Endpoint, the server returns the token as a JSON object:

```
{
  "access_token": "ie3b1941J24Ev2hsR...",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 299,
  "userName": "admin@mycoolwebsite.com",
  ".issued": "Tue, 23 Feb 2016 21:54:09 GMT",
  ".expires": "Tue, 23 Feb 2016 21:59:09 GMT"
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible if the server returns the Token as a ReturnUrl?

**More Info**

I have a mobile app which uses a *WebView* that loads the Login page of my website.

In the website, after clicking on the Login button, it sends a `POST` request to the Token endpoint and saves the received OAuth Token in a HTML5 session storage.

Then on the mobile side, I need to extract this token from the *WebView* using Javascript and use it for my next requests to the server.

Is this the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the OAuth2 [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2), the authorization server will return the token in an HTTP redirect, which is what I understand you are looking for.

However, in this flow it is the authorization server that will show the user the login screen, not your web application.